# loop all objects in aws config using boto3

Tags: python, boto3, aws-sdk, config, aws-cli

i was new to aws boto3.
Goal : i want pull all compliant& [non-compliant](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/APIReference/API_Compliance.html) rule from [aws-config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/) service and write in txt file as non-compliant_config.txt

The problem is when i when run this code , its not iterating through all the rules(my guess it stops at first 25)

```
import boto3
#counter to count total number of rules(objects) this code iterated.
count = 0 

client = boto3.client('config')
response = client.describe_config_rules()

for i in response['ConfigRules']:
    count = count +1 
    print(i)

print(count)
```

last line in my code print(count) says 25

Final point : i want to print(or write to txt file) all the AWS config-rules.
Note : i also tried to look at [boto3 pagination documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/config.html#paginators), but i cant understand it to how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have to use `NextToken` from `describe_config_rules`, to keep iterating further. Alternatively you can use `get_paginator('describe_config_rules')` as explained in the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/config.html#ConfigService.Client.describe_config_rules).

Comment: get_paginator('describe_config_rules') worked !

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('config')
count = 0 

paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_config_rules')

rules = paginator.paginate()

for rule in rules:
    for j in i['ConfigRules'] :
        count = count + 1
        print(j)
```

This code with loop through all the AWS config rules.

solution credits : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70647301/7995771